# Can I get updates (DirSync Cookie) in Active Directory with paging?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, adsi, directorysearcher

I am using DirSync Control (Cookie) to get the latest changes using the below technique. Is it possible to get that result with pagination ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/polling-for-changes-using-the-dirsync-control

Example: If 500 updates have happened, can i get updates from 1-50, or 51-100 (paging with skip) ?

Answer (score 0):

The result returned is paginated. You need to put the cookie, returned from the previous response into the next request. However, from my experience the number of changes on every page may vary. You can set the upper border, but I would not recommend to rely on it. If you want to display/send changes in batches with predefined size additional processing should be done on the client side

Comment: What additional changes can be done client side ? My requirement is to get incremental changes in batches (not ```MoreData``` functionality)

Comment: @KushalArora From my experience MoreData is the only way how you can get changes using DirSync control. You can set properties like PageSize to limit the changes count returned. To get next page you need a cookie from previous response